# MYSQL check all rows and meet conditions

Tags: if-statement, case

I am struggling to get required output in MYSQL.

I have such table:

| Result_ID | Code | Rule |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 39566 | O | 0 |
| 39566 | G | 0 |
| 39566 | R | 1135 |
| 40115 | R | 1135 |

I would like to apply criteria that if code = R and rule <> 0 then 'passed' ELSE 'manual'. But it should check all rows with the same result_id.

I've tried writing like this:

```
  SELECT  DISTINCT
  [RESULT_ID] 
  ,CODE
  ,RULE
  ,CASE WHEN CODE ='R' AND RULE_DETAIL_ID <> 0 THEN 'Passed' 
  WHEN CODE <> 'R' THEN 'MANUAL'
  END as abc
```

But it is checking only one row. How to make it to check all rows for the same result_id?

The outcome should look like this

| Result_ID | Code | Rule | abc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 39566 | O | 0 | MANUAL |
| 39566 | G | 0 | MANUAL |
| 39566 | R | 1135 | MANUAL |
| 40115 | R | 1135 | Passed |

Comment: Which version of MySql?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to to use `exists` to correlate on the same Id value

```
select *, 
    case when exists (
            select * from t x where x.result_id=t.result_id 
                and not( code='r' and rule != 0 ) 
        ) then 'MANUAL' else 'Passed' end
from t
```

[See DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b5be6d8fc18f48d80ae19299b1c4bf6b)